# Why should not we pluck fragrant flowers for puja in the evening?

Tags: puja, superstitions

Can we pluck flowers in the evening (before sunset and/or after sunset)? To be more specific, can we pluck fragrant flowers in the evening and decorate our puja room in our house. Because I have heard people saying we can decorate the room with flowers only in the morning and not after sunset.

Is that true??? Does scriptures says any reason for the same.

Thanks.